# SpriteKit screen size--how to get the correct size of images on a real phone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Why does my app look different from the simulator when I run it on my real phone?

I am making a game using spritekit.  When I test it in the iPhone 5 simulator, the size of the screen and the size of the images are exactly as I want them, but then when I run the program on my actual iPhone 5, the images show up too big, parts of the top and bottom of the screen are cut off, and the left and right of the screen don't extend all the way to the sides of the phone--there's a letterboxing effect from left to right on the screen.

All my images are named with @2x, so they should work fine with retina screens.  Here's the code relating to screen size that I use when I initialize my SKScene:

```
GameScene *scene = [GameScene unarchiveFromFile:@"GameScene"];
scene.size = self.view.frame.size;
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
```

I've tried each of the available SKSceneScaleModes and none of them help--they each just give a different outcome that doesn't look right.  I'm using AspectFill simply because that mode does work correctly in the simulator.

I've also tried sizing the screen like this, just as something to try, but that didn't help either:

```
GameScene *scene = [GameScene unarchiveFromFile:@"GameScene"];
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
scene.size = screenRect.size;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note, my phone is running ios 7 whereas the simulator is simulating ios 8.  From some further reading I did, this could have something to do with the problem.  I want the app to be backwards compatible with ios 7, so I want this solved still.  Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It was indeed due to the fact that the simulator was simulating ios 8 while my device was on ios 7.  ios 8 automatically changes the coordinate system when you go into landscape mode (the native mode of my game) while ios 7 does not.  The fix was simple once I figured that out--just detect which os the device is running, and, if it's lower than ios 8, swap the height and width dimensions of the screen:

```
if (NSFoundationVersionNumber <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
    CGSize fixedSize = CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.height, screenRect.size.width);
    scene.size = fixedSize;
}
else
    scene.size = self.view.frame.size;
```